# How to close only one instance of buffer?

Tags: vim

I'm using `:bd!` to close current buffer. Sometimes, I open long file in two split buffer to see different parts of the file.

But if I use `:bd!` in a buffer, both of split buffers are closing.

How can I close only one instance of the buffer?

**Update:**

I wrote a function to do it, but it doesn't working:

```
function! g:CloseSplitOrBuffer()
    " Is the file opened at least two times?
    if bufwinnr(expand('%:p')) > 1
        execute ':q'
    else
        execute ':bd!'
    endif
endfunction
```

The `if condition` is `true` always, even I close all other splits.

Comment: `:q` - *9 more to go...*

Comment: I dont want to use `:q` because it will close buffers completely. When I close the last open buffer with `:q`, vim is closing.
But `:bd!` will do not close the vim, instead creating a blank buffer.

Comment: If you have split your screen with `(v)split`, you can close one split with `:q`. That doesn't close your buffer or vim. Only when you do `:q` on your last open buffer and no split screens, vim will close. If you want to create a blank buffer, just use `:new`. *(or I'm misunderstanding what you want)*

Comment: `:bd!` is creating a new buffer instead of closing vim, if I try to close last split view.

I have a mapping like this: `nnoremap <silent> <leader>q :bd!<CR>`.

How I combine `:q` and `:bd!`? What I want is: "close the split view. If it was last split view, create a new buffer".

Comment: So this is your workflow (?): `if (IsSplitWindow) then CloseWindow else CloseBuffer end`

Comment: It's the same instance of the same buffer. What you have two of is *windows* and you can close one without affecting what's displayed in the other.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yeah, exactly it is.

Comment: You could try `winnr("$") > 1` instead

Comment: It does not worked, returning `false` :(

Comment: I have no idea why. It returns 1 when I have multiple windows and 0 when I have only one window open. What does `echo winnr("$")` return when you have one window open? What does it return when you have two windows open?

Comment: I guess I find the problem, vim is counting NERDTree window as buffer. It works, now. Can you post an answer so I can accept it. Working condition is: `if winnr('$') > 1`  Thank you. :)

Comment: Thank you but you answered 90% of your oww question :). Post it an you'll have my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
function! g:CloseSplitOrBuffer()
    " Is the file opened at least two times?
    if winnr('$') > 1
        execute ':q'
    else
        execute ':bd!'
    endif
endfunction
```

Thanks to @LievenKeersmaekers

Answer (score 1):

You can close the current window: `Ctl-w c`

You can also close all the windows but the current one: `Ctl-w o`